# Simplest way to output file ages instead of filedates by ls?

Tags: command-line-interface

What is the simplest way to output file ages instead of filedates by ls command?

Like "1 hour", "2 days", "3 weeks", etc.

(Sometimes file age is much more significant than date)

Comment: Gnome's Nautilus does something similar.  Perhaps you can check how it's done there?

Answer (score 0):

I get the UNIX-Systemdate in seconds with NOW=`date +%s`
Then I get the UNIX-Timestamp of the file with OLD=`stat -c %Z filename`

And finally I get the age by expr $NOW - $OLD.